# Name this network topology? multiple star networks sparsely linked by leaves

Tags: network-programming, topology

I am trying to find existing examples (or even the name) of a network structure a colleague of mine is working on. The network looks like a number of central hubs, each with its own leaf nodes, but a few of the leaves are connected to 2 hubs. The hubs are not connected to each other.

Answer (score 2):

It's a kind of mesh, but it's more constrained than that. Could you call it a mesh of stars?

It's actually somewhat similar to internet topology, in particular that of the early internet - sites have networks, and some of the nodes at the edges of a network (edge routers) are connected to one or more adjacent networks.

Comment: mesh of stars.. There is something called a snowflake network topology, which seems to fit the bill, and is described as a stars of stars network, while not being a (more common) star bus network or star ring network, or extended star network. Found some links on it: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5439/?include_text=1 , and some random pictures. The name would come from lining up snowflakes (each of which looks like a star network topology). Where they touch, a new network connection is formed and you indeed get the network I was looking for. Quite exotic.

Comment: That document says "The first topology is the snowflake model.  In this type of network, only the very core of the network is meshed. The edges of the network are formed as trees rooted in the core".  That doesn't sound like your description, although I can see the similarity.

Comment: Not sure then what the difference is between an extended star network and a snowflake network. I'll look a bit more into it tomorrow. Thanks for the help though :-)